# Angular localized URLs for SEO, no locale parameter for default language, using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is how I currently set up the base state in my angular app

```
  $stateProvider.state(AppState.APP, {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/{locale:(?:en|ja)}',
    views: {
      app: {
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
      }
    }
  });
```

And there's a logic that redirects you to `domain.com/{locale}/` if you access `domain.com/`

Assuming that my site's default language is English, I want to drop the `en` from the URL. Example:

- http://domain.com/about will show the About page in English
- http://domain.com/ja/about will show the About page in Japanese

Is there a good way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this article could help you: https://fadeit.dk/blog/2015/03/12/angularjs-seo-for-angular-translate/

In the article, it provides a step-by-step tutorial of AngularJS SEO friendly translations. However, in the article, its default language is set to `'da'`, so all you have to do is to change the default language to `'en'` and the other language to `'jp'`, it also allows multi-language scaling.

For example of changing default to `'en'`:

```
var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
if(absUrl.indexOf('/jp/') !== -1){
  $scope.activeLang = 'jp';
}
else{
  $scope.activeLang = 'en';
}
$translate.use($scope.activeLang);
```

and

```
//Construct url base
var port = $location.port();
//Port can be omitted on 80 or 443
port = (port === 80 || port === 443) ? '' : ':' + port;
var urlBase = $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + port;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(){
  $scope.jpUrl =  urlBase + '/jp' + $location.url();
  $scope.enUrl =  urlBase + $location.url();
});
```

Hope this helps you, and please inform me if I misunderstood your problem :).